# render props doesn't display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I am new to React and I am learning about the props.
My prop doesn't display color on Events.js
I got "I am a car" and red didn't display.

This is my component Welcome.js :

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Welcome(props) {
    return <h2>I am a {props.color} Car!</h2>;
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(<Welcome color="red"/>, document.getElementById('root'));

  export default Welcome;
```

my page Events.js:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import  Calendar from "react-calendar"; 
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Form from "./Form";
import Welcome from "./Welcome"



function Events() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <Form/>
     
      
    <Welcome/>

     
    </div>
  );
}



export default Events;
```

Comment: This works fine for me. Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the prop in `Events.js`. This means the value of `props.color` is `undefined` when the render function is called. `undefined` within curly braces will be [ignored by React](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored).

You can add a guard to ensure that you see an error if the prop is not defined:

```
function Welcome(props) {
    if (props.color == null) {
        throw 'color should be defined';
    }

    return <h2>I am a {props.color} Car!</h2>;
}
```